# Understanding scala types for functions

Tags: scala

A simple function literal can be written as

def add(x : Int) = x + 2

In the above example I understand add is a function that takes an Int and gives an Int. Its type is add: (x: Int)Int

It is very clear.

But the below example which is of type Option[Int] => Int it is a bit unclear

```
scala>  def matchFunction : Option[Int] => Int = {
     |   case Some(x) => x
     |   case None => 0
     | }
matchFunction: Option[Int] => Int
```

In the second example, can anyone explain why the type should it not be

```
def matchFunction (x : Option[Int]) : Int
```

Also please explain what is the difference between the above function and the one below that uses match from a type perspective

```
def matchFunction (x : Option[Int]) : Int = x match {
  case Some(x) => x
  case None => 0
}
```

Comment: `add` is a method not function.  so you want to know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala

Comment: @chengpohi, why is add a method, but matchFunction a function. Both are def, so why is one different to the other?

Comment: `matchFunction` is a parameterless method, so you can use it like a variable, and it's returning a `function`. equal:  `def matchFunction(): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is one of functional programming aspects: higher-order functions - those who takes other functions as parameters, or whose result is a function. `Option[Int] => Int` is an anonymous function which takes `Option[Int]` as a parameter and returns `Int`, anonymous function can always be expressed using `def`, `def matchFunction(x : Option[Int]): Int = { ... }` is just another variant to express `Option[Int] => Int = { ... }`. Higher-order functions are useful for generalization, polymorphism. So you may pass your `matchFunction` to function which takes `Option[Int] => Int` function as a parameter. `List(Some(1), None, Some(2)).map(matchFunction)` will give you `List(1, 0, 2)`.

https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/higher_order_functions

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand now.